# Puxar dadoss de uma input

Tags: javascript, jquery

```
<html>
   <head>
   </head>
   <body>
   <input type="text" id="dias">
   <input type="date" id="ativacao">
   <input type="date" id="vencimento">
  <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
    <script>
         $('#ativacao')[0].valueAsDate = new Date();

$('#ativacao').change(function() {
  var date = this.valueAsDate;
  date.setDate(date.getDate() + $("#dias").val();
  $('#vencimento')[0].valueAsDate = date;
});

$('#ativacao').change();
    </script>
   </body>
   </html>``
```

estou com esse script aqui, ali no 14 seria os dias, teria como colocar algo ali pra puxar o valor de uma input (tanto de dias?)
coloquei corforme disseram abaixo, mas ele ta retornando datas aleatorias
sou novo em jquery

Comment: Você pode definir o 14 em uma variável ou então acessar o valor no jQuery com $("#inputId").val(); [Veja a documentação](http://api.jquery.com/val/)

Answer (score 0):

Olá, boa tarde!

Segue um exemplo que fiz para tentar ajudá-lo.

```js
$('#ativacao')[0].valueAsDate = new Date();

$('#ativacao').change(function() {
  var data = this.valueAsDate;
  
  data.setDate(parseInt(data.getDate()) + parseInt($('#dias').val()));
  
  $('#vencimento')[0].valueAsDate = data;
  
});

$("#executar").click(function(){
    $('#ativacao').change();
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>


   <input type="number" id="dias" placeholder="dias" />
   <input type="date" id="ativacao" />
   <input type="date" id="vencimento" />
   <input type="button" id="executar" value="Executar" />
```